# React onClick not registers on initially disabled button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Once facebook sdk loads i remove the disabled attr like this: `this.refs.fbBtn.getDOMNode().removeAttribute('disabled');` but the`onClick` evt listener never gets registered because the button is disabled initially.

```
<Button disabled={true} ref="fbBtn" type="button" bsStyle="primary"
        onClick={this.handleClick}>Facebook</Button>
```

any idea how to solve this?

btw should i store a disabled value in state like `disabled={this.state.disabled}` or by using ref?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should absolutely do it with `disabled={this.state.disabled}` instead. When you access the DOM directly, React won't know when the state of the DOM has changed. So you need to tell React that, and the simplest way is to use state/props.

Comment: okay, but what about the original problem that onChange event listener won't be added on a disabled button?

Comment: If you tell React that it's not disabled by setting the prop from state instead, the click handler will be called.